# Getting Internet Access from Computer to Computer Ethernet

Tags: windows-xp, internet

I'm currently running Windows 7 on my main machine and before today has a secondary machine running Ubuntu.

I finally decided to install XP on my second machine as I thought it may be more useful than having Ubuntu for me.

My Ubuntu setup before worked perfectly - I have an ethernet cable running from my main machine (that gets internet via WiFi) into my secondary machine and Ubuntu recognised this and gave me internet access!

Unfortunately this has not happened with XP. XP doesn't seem to do anything no matter how many times I plug and unplug the cable. I've had a little look into connection settings, but I can't seem to get anywhere.

IP Settings:

- Main PC: 192.168.0.103, 255.255.255.0.1
- XP PC: 192.168.137.207, 255.255.255.0, Gateway: 192.168.137.1

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about your settings, plugging/unplugging the cable won't help if there's something wrong in your configuration. Did you wipe your Ubuntu installation? Maybe you had some specific settings there. I assume you didn't change anything on the Windows 7 machine, did you?

Comment: I wiped my partition (just as I did before I installed Ubuntu and Ubuntu worked fine). I've now re-installed the Broadcom drivers for my device and it still doesn't work. (And no - I didn't change the Windows 7 machine at all)

Comment: Shouldn't be the drivers causing this issue. By being specific about your settings I meant adding your actual connection settings to the question you posted: For example, have you manually bridged your WiFi and Ethernet connections on the Win 7 machine or did you use Internet Connection Sharing? Which IP Addresses do the machines have? etc.

Comment: I didn't do anything. I just plugged it in and expected it to work (as it did with Ubuntu). Is there anything I should be doing?

Comment: Yes, helping us help you by telling us about your network settings :) I quote you on this one: "Try and be more specific if at all possible in all questions you ask online as it's difficult to solve problems such as this without specifics". It could be the simple problem of a wrong IP address configuration in your XP machine.

Comment: I haven't really done any configuration - I'm very unaware of my network layout. I restarted both computers and now on the XP machine "Wireless Network Connection on JOE-PC" pops up and it appears to be connected fine (in the status is says "Connected", and it has the duration and speed). When I try to acess the internet however (via Internet Explorer) it insists that "The page cannot be displayed". Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't really help - Do you know how to [find out your IP address](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-out-Your-IP-Address)? Do this on both Windows PCs and include the IPv4 Addresses, Subnet Masks and Gateways and in your question above. Or just do screenshots.

Comment: Main PC: 192.168.0.103, 255.255.255.0.1                             XP PC: 192.168.137.207, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.137.1

Comment: Thanks, I was able to post an answer. For the future: Please edit your original quesiton above using the `edit` button so people don't have to scroll through all the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, from seeing your IP settings the problem is obvious: In order for the two machines to "see" each other, their ethernet connections have to be in the same IP subnet.

Your Win 7 machine has two network ports, the WiFi and the ethernet port. You need to find out the ethernet address of the Windows 7 machine.

To sum it up, [change your Windows XP machine's IP addresses](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-your-IP-Address-%28Windows%29) to:

- IP: 192.168.137.123 (just as an example)
- Gateway: The ethernet IP Address of your Win 7 machine

Comment: I just did this and all it did was remove the "Wireless Network Connection on JOE-PC" option in my "network connections" (It didn't work :( )

Comment: I understand what's happening. I think you didn't post the right IP address of your Windows 7 machine. It should have two network connections (namely the WiFi and the ethernet), but we need the one of the ethernet (i.e. the thing that connects both PCs).

Comment: Ah ok. Well my Windows 7 IP of the "Local Area Connection" is as follows (you were right - I previously used the Wifi): 192.168.137.1, 255.255.255.0 and no default gateway.

Comment: Ok then your old options were good, I guess. Let me think. Can you run `ping 192.168.137.1` from your XP machine (but reset the IP settings like they were before, so that both are in the 137. subnet)?

Comment: Phew, I'm really out of suggestions here. If you change the IP Settings from manual to automatic, does that work?

Comment: Hm, as your settings on the Win7 machine seem to be fine, I can't see what else you could do with the XP machine. There's one thing though: If you say it worked in Ubuntu without any further configuration, maybe you can boot off an Ubuntu Live CD and from there, enter a Terminal, type `ifconfig` and find out what settings Ubuntu had. That's really my last resort.

Comment: I checked the Ubuntu settings when I had it installed and I remember that they are exactly the same of that, that the XP machine has. *sigh* - I wish Microsoft products actually worked..

Comment: I'm sorry, I really wish I could help you more, but I can't think of anything else and my experience with Internet Connection Sharing in Windows isn't the best.